# How do i have my bot send a message to any user by typing their user id on command?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I wanted to know if its possible to set a command where i can just use some user id and send them a message? for example, if i want to use command “send” and then the bot will just say “type the users id you want to send the message to”, then i would just put the id of some user and then the bot will send whatever message i have my bot send to that user. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a [message collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors).

```js
// message is the Message that the user sent
// client is the Client/bot

message.channel.send('Type the user id that you want to send the message to.')
  .then(() => message.channel.awaitMessages(
    // only include messages from the original author
    m => m.author.id === message.author.id),
    // This stops collecting after one message that passes the above filter
    {max: 1}
  ))
    .then(collected => {
      const id = collected.first().content
      client.users.fetch(id)
        .then(user => user.send('some message'))
        .catch(() => message.channel.send(`${id} is not a valid user ID!`)
    })
```

Comment: ,nice this worked but can you also tell how to do this exact thing in a message collector but that does not have the await time time?? so like it can collect as many messages without a timer.